# Как правильно сказать?

Tags: грамотная-речь

"Противоположность кого-то" или "противоположность кому-то"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы употребляете это слово с предлогом  (**В** ПРОТИВОПОЛОЖНОСТЬ), то требуется дательный падеж (кому?чему?) Здесь "в противоположность" выступает в роли предлога.

Думаю, что "противоположность" в значении "антипод" может употребляться и с дательным,  и с родительным падежом: *"Она была полной противоположностью своему мужу", "Ты полная его противоположность"*. Родительный, скорее всего, более предпочтителен в книжной речи, а дательный падеж используется чаще в разговорном стиле. Так что оба Ваши варианта, мне кажется,  приемлемы, но правильнее, я думаю,  "противоположность кого-то".

Обоснованные возражения приму с благодарностью.

Answer (score 0):

Наверное, в прошедшем времени возможно употребление с дательным падежом, а в настоящем - с родительным.